# webscocket in a different port in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, port, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My elastic Bean stalks all other ports are secured/restricted access. This is achieved by security groups where inbound access is given restricted. They can only be accessed from certian IP's

Now I have a websocket running in node Js in the same machine.That should be exposed to public. I hosted this in a different port. Which protocols / ports should i enable so that this websocket alone is exposed to public?

What should be the security policy for this?